# Using sudo aptitude/apt-get update does not work

Tags: apt, command-line, updates, bash, aptitude

[image]

Trying to update via terminal via aptitude or apt-get is not working. There is no other package management program running in the background or any other user.

I tried both, `sudo aptitude update` and `sudo apt-get update` just in case. Same problem.

Trying to do it via Update manager throws this output:

`W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)`

Internet connection is working since I could create this question.

Tried to do: a `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -fr` but it only helped in executing both apt-get and aptitude to see them fail again at the end with the same problem.

What else could be locking the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me is a weird one.

I first cleared out the apt list, to make sure.

Then proceeded to check if there was a program locking it (Even though there was nothing in memory that suggest it so): `lsof|grep dpkg/lock`

Then lastly I checked to see if there was the lock file in the apt list. Nothing.

I remembered yesterday we had changed ISP (We have 2 ISP connections). So just for "going back to origins" sake and changed the ISP back.

Everything works as it should. aptitude, update manager, synaptic, software center and apt-get. But then a new question: Why did changing the ISP create this problem.