# Unable to install updates or anny programs after upgrade

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates

After I upgraded my Ubuntu to 12.04
I cant install or update any programs, it keep on giving an error saying `Failed to download repository information`

I have tried with **apt-get** in terminal and it also failed .

I have tried solutions in other threads, but it did not resolve my problem.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135438/using-sudo-aptitude-apt-get-update-does-not-work)?

I actually researched which problem I could solve for hours. Then I did yours. I think it took me an hour or so. Then I found my answer. Then I saw a previous answer given to you as I posted mine.I don't know much but it seems like I am on the same page now.